# Replace hour of chrono::time_point?

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

How can I change just the hour of an existing `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point`?

For example, say I wanted to implement this function:

```
void set_hour(std::chrono::system_clock::time_point& tp, int hour) {
  // Do something here to set the hour
}

std::chrono::system_clock::time_point midnight_jan_1_2022{std::chrono::seconds{1640995200}};

set_hour(midnight_jan_1_2022, 11);
// midnight_jan_1_2022 is now 11am on Jan 1 2022
....
```

Comment: Do you have access to C++20?

Comment: Yes, C++23 actually

Comment: You can't have access to a standard that doesn't exist yet. In any case, [`std::year_month_day` exists and can be useful](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/year_month_day).

Comment: Well, whatever parts of 23 g++ supports as described at https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx23

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer depends on exactly what you mean.  The simplest interpretation is that you want to take whatever date `tp` points to (say `yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss.fff...`), and create:  `yyyy-mm-dd hour:00:00.000...`.

Another possible interpretation is that `yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss.fff...` is transformed into `yyyy-mm-dd hour:MM:ss.fff...`.

In either event C++20 makes this easy, and if you don't yet have access to C++20 `<chrono>`, then there exists [a free, open-source header-only library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) that emulates C++20 `<chrono>` and works with C++11/14/17.

If you want to zero the minute, second and subsecond fields as described in the first interpretation that is:

```
void
set_hour(std::chrono::system_clock::time_point& tp, int hour)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;

    auto day = floor<days>(tp);
    tp = day + hours{hour};
}
```

I.e. you simply floor the `time_point` to days-precision and then add the desired hours.

The second interpretation is slightly more complicated:

```
void
set_hour(std::chrono::system_clock::time_point& tp, int hour)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;

    auto day = floor<days>(tp);
    hh_mm_ss hms{tp - day};
    tp = day + hours{hour} + hms.minutes() + hms.seconds() + hms.subseconds();
}
```

Here you have to discover and recover the {minutes, seconds, subseconds} fields to re-apply them to the desired date (along with the desired `hour`).  `hh_mm_ss` is a C++20 `{hours, minutes, seconds, subseconds}` data structure that automates the conversion from a duration into a field structure so that you can more easily replace the hours field.

Both of these solutions will give the same answer for your example input:

```
2022-01-01 11:00:00.000000
```

since the input has zeroed minutes, seconds and subseconds fields already.